# How to Calculate Appropriate Load Required When Converting Voltages?

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter, amperage

I have a cabinet with a power strip with various devices being powered:

1. RaspberryPI (5V / 2.5A) x2
2. Mini Smart Router (5V/1A)
3. TP-Link Switch (9V/0.6A)
4. USFF Computers (19V/7.1A) x2

I've been ruminating the idea of putting together a single power supply to power everything. I am no Electrical Engineer, but I am handy!

I would rather over engineer something (power rating wise) vs having the thing run hot and blow up.

With the wide range of voltages I will have to step-up or down the voltage. I am starting with a 12V 30A supply (not sure if this is best approach).

I wanted to know how to properly add/convert to ensure I have an ample supply load.

20.8A (adding everything above) I am not sure if this is correct considering I am stepping up and down voltage.

**TL;DR:** How do I properly calculate total supply when stepping up and stepping down? Should I start with a different power supply, 24V instead of 12V and then step everything down?

[image: Power Supply]

[image: 12V to 19V]

[image: 12V to 9V]

[image: 12V to 5V]

Comment: Your 19V/8A and some of your 5V/3A units will be pushed to almost their limit. I wouldn't do that if I were you.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct .. I would have to at least double the amps on the 19V and 5V converters or do 2 of each.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/RCNUN-12V-to-19V-20A-380W-Voltage-Booster-Power-Supply-DC-Converter-Step-Up-Regulator/32665315918.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10325_10546_10343_10340_10548_10341_10696_10084_10083_10618_10307_10135_10133_10059_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620,searchweb201603_11,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=8f56b1af-a22b-46fc-aa33-b3ea4d35664f-14&algo_pvid=8f56b1af-a22b-46fc-aa33-b3ea4d35664f&priceBeautifyAB=0) is your 19 V converter, [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-DC-DC-12V-24V-to-9V-4A-36W-Auto-Car-Converter-Buck-Module-Step/1621679880.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.160.1e915ef83nM4Be&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10325_10546_10343_10340_10548_10341_10696_10084_10083_10618_10307_10135_10133_10059_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620,searchweb201603_11,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=5ccdbe49-fb7f-46ec-bf27-3e8652622e62-23&algo_pvid=5ccdbe49-fb7f-46ec-bf27-3e8652622e62&priceBeautifyAB=0) your 9 V converter, and [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DC-DC-Converter-Step-Down-12V-to-5V-24V-to-5V-10A-50W-daygreen-Newest-Type/32585217993.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.17.1abb4406vRoZOa&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10325_10546_10343_10340_10548_10341_10696_10084_10083_10618_10307_10135_10133_10059_100031_10103_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620,searchweb201603_11,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=4370f4e3-9654-4532-bdda-c7abd7d5c68a-2&algo_pvid=4370f4e3-9654-4532-bdda-c7abd7d5c68a&priceBeautifyAB=0) your 5 V DC/DC converter.

Your 12 V power supply looks fine.